# How to assign label text to a determined variable on JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm making a Java program in which I'm using JavaFX for a more polished GUI. Problem is, I have to assign a variable to a certain label (text), so that when I change the variable, the label text also changes.

On Swing this is easy to do, but in JavaFX you use fxml to build your user interface. How do I assign a variable to this label, since the variable is obviously from a .java class and the file  where I make these changes is a fxml?

This is the label code by the way

```
<Label fx:id="palavra" layoutX="424.0" layoutY="148.0" prefWidth="177.0" text="(this is where the variable must assign)">
```

Comment: If I read your question correctly, in the ?NameController.java file put `@FXML public static Label palavra;`

Answer (score 3):

Brian is right. When you assign a controller to your FXML file, annotate the Label called palavra with @FXML. Not necessarily "public static" though.

```
@FXML public Label palavra;
```